# Creating two lists derived from an analysed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, if-statement

I am in the process of creating a function that can check multiple conditions of my dataset and then return two lists.

- List 1: Items to perform X
- List 2: Items to perform Y

Sample data:

```
   Product   Variable     Value
0      A       Sell       0.1
1      B       Keep      -1.2
2      C       Sell       0.3
3      D       Swap       0.1
4      E       Swap       0.1
```

Ideal outcome:

```
Sell; A, C 
Swap; 'Nothing to swap this week'
```

Error when running:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

My code so far:

```
def weekly_forcasting(df):

    a = df['Swap or Sell']
    b = df['Current Value']

    if (a == 'Sell') and (b > 0).any():
        return ('Product_Label')
        if (a == 'Sell') and (b < 0).any():
          return 'Nothing to sell this week'
        if (a == 'Swap') and (b > 0).any():
          return 'Nothing to swap this week'
        if (a == 'Swap') and (b < 0).any():
          return ('Product_Label')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b = df['Current Value']` makes `b` a series as the error message suggests. So  ideally you want to use `.loc`, for instance you probably want

```
selling_list = (
    df.loc[
        (df["Swap or Sell"]=="Sell") & (df["Current Value"]>0)
    ]["Product_Label"].tolist() if 
    len(df.loc[
        (df["Swap or Sell"]=="Sell") & (df["Current Value"]>0)
    ]["Product_Label"].tolist()) > 0 
    else "nothing to sell this week"
)
```

and similarly you could define `swapping_list` and do a `return selling_list, swapping_list`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `numpy.select`

```
import numpy as np

# create a list of condtions
conditions = [
    (df['Swap or Sell'] == 'Sell') & (df['Current Value'] > 0),
    (df['Swap or Sell'] == 'Sell') & (df['Current Value'] < 0),
    (df['Swap or Sell'] == 'Swap') & (df['Current Value'] > 0),
    (df['Swap or Sell'] == 'Swap') & (df['Current Value'] < 0),
]
# create a list of chices that mtach a statisifed condition
choices = [
    df['Product_Label'],
    'There are no Sell recommendations today',
    'There are no Swap recommendations today',
    df['Product_Label'],
]

# create a new by using numpy.select
df['data'] = np.select(conditions, choices, 'Keep')
```

Then just access the info you want using boolean indexing

```
df.loc[df['Swap or Sell'] == 'Sell', 'data']
```